# Proof Explanation: Sequences, convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, intuition

Can anyone please explain the theorem/proof in the picture attached? There is a theorem that states that if $X$ converges to $x$, then all subsequences of $X$ converge and converge to $x$. However, in this theorem, it is just considering the subsequences that are convergent. Moreover, I fail to understand the last two lines of the proof, can anyone explain those, maybe by breaking it down a bit?

Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

(1).Let $S$ be an infinite subset of $\Bbb N .$   Then $(y_n)_{n\in S}$ converges to $y$ iff, whenever $J$ is an open interval containing $y,$ the set $\{n\in S:y_n\not \in J\}$ is finite.

(2). Suppose  $A=(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is bounded and does not converge to $x.$ Take $r,s>0$ such that the set $U=\{n\in \Bbb N: a_n\not \in (-s+x,r+x)\}$ is infinite.

Then $B=(a_n)_{n\in U}$  is a subsequence of $A$ and is a bounded sequence, so $B$ has a convergent subsequence $C=(a_n)_{n\in V}$ (where $V$ is some infinite subset  of $U$) with $C$ converging to  $y.$ But since $a_n\not \in (-s+x,r+s)$ for every $n\in V,$ we have $y\not \in (-s+x,r+x),$ so $y\ne x.$

So if the bounded sequence $A$ does not converge to $x$ then $A$ has a subsequence converging to some $y\ne x.$

Remarks. I think that is a better way to state the result, as the usual def'n of a subsequence  allows $A$ to be a subsequence of $A.$ Consider any sequence $X$  to be some (any)  function $f$ whose domain is an infinite subset of $\Bbb N,$ and a subsequence  of $X$ to be  $f$ restricted to some infinite subset of the domain of  $f$.

Comment: For bounded $A=(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ let $u=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{m>n}a_m$ and $d=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{m>n}a_m.$  We can show that $A$ has a subsequence $D$ converging to $d$ and a subsequence $U$ converging to $u.$ Now $A$ converges to $ x $ iff $u=d=x.$ So if $A$ does not converge to $x$ then $u,d$  cannot both equal $x,$ so at least one of $U,D$ converges to something other than $x.$

Comment: Thank you. This makes more sense. So it is necessary that at least one subsequence of A has a different limit than others for A to diverge?

Comment: For a bounded sequence, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You have that every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence by Bolzano Weirstrass. Let's call the limit $x$. The contradiction from the theorem just formalizes the idea that, in fact, the whole sequence can be thought as a subsequence itself, so it has to converge to the same place. If not, you then are able to find a subsequence that diverges from the original limit where all the sequences are going.

Comment: How can the whole sequence be thought as a subsequence itself? Also, would a proof that goes like this: (Since all the m-tails of the sequence are subsequences, this implies that they converge to x and therefore, the whole sequence must converge to x) is valid?

Comment: That's the underlying reasoning on the proof. What you have to do is say: alright, lets say that the whole sequence goes to a different place. Then, the whole thing might or might not converge, however, you will have a convergent subsequence. You make that convergent subsequence a new sequence Y. Then, it has a subsequence (which is also subsequence of X) that has to go to x. That is the contradiction, because if Y is convergent, has to go to the same place than its subsequences.

Comment: How is it a contradiction? If it has a convergent subsequence, and that, will go to x, and any subsequence of the sequence will go to x. I don't see how it encompasses all of the subequences that x will have?

Comment: Wait, are you saying that we assume that there is atleast one subsequence that doesn't converge but because it will be bounded, then by the Bolzano Weistress theorem, we'll get a subsequence of our divergent subsequence that will converge and its limit will be x because it is also a subsequence of the original sequence? After this, I don't get the contradiction?

Comment: If the sequence is bounded, at least one subsequence converges. For example, the limsup and the liminf.